# How to use the #Requires keyword for DLLs?

Tags: c#, powershell

How can I use the `#Requires` keyword to check for a specific dll? This is the code I have got, which requires the file `Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll` to be in the same folder as the script.

```
# Load DLL containing classes & interfaces
Add-Type -path "Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll"

# Provides methods for controlling the Search service. This 
# interface manages settings and objects that affect the search engine 
# across catalogs. 
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231485(v=vs.85).aspx
$sm = New-Object Microsoft.Search.Interop.CSearchManagerClass

# Retrieves a catalog by name and creates a new ISearchCatalogManager 
# object for that catalog.
$catalog = $sm.GetCatalog("SystemIndex")

# Resets the underlying catalog by rebuilding the databases 
# and performing a full indexing. 
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266414(v=vs.85).aspx
$catalog.Reset()
```

Comment: Can you not just use `-ErrorAction Stop` on your `Add-Type`? What else would you want to happen?

Comment: There are of course several ways to ensure the file is in place. But I wanna know out of curiosity how to leverage this PowerShell keyword, as it was designed for this specific purpose, wasn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple function to test for existence of an assembly should suffice, if all you want is to check for existence of a specific assembly in the filesystem (i.e. in the same folder as the script) or in the GAC.

The function will accept an assembly name with or without a path. It tests for an assembly in the script folder (if no path element). Then if `searchGAC` param specified, tests for existence in the GAC. If it finds the assembly anywhere, it will load it, otherwise, will throw an exception.

```
# requires function
function Get-Assembly ([string]$dllName, [switch]$searchGAC) {
  if ($dllName.Split('\\').Count -eq 1) {
    $dllName = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $dllName
  }
  if (Test-Path $dllName -PathType Leaf) {
    Add-Type -path $dllName
  } else {
    $found = $false
  }
  if (!$found -and $searchGAC) {
    $dllName = ($dllName -split '\\')[-1]
    $assembly = [appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | Select -ExpandProperty Modules | where {$_.Name -match $dllName}
    if ($assembly) {
      [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load($assembly.Assembly.FullName)
      $found = $true
    }
  }
  if (!$found) {
    throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] "$dllName not found."
  }
}
Set-Alias -Name Requires -Value Get-Assembly -Force


# your code from here, with the requires added in
# Load DLL containing classes & interfaces
Requires -dllName 'Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll' -searchGAC

# Provides methods for controlling the Search service. This 
# interface manages settings and objects that affect the search engine 
# across catalogs. 
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231485(v=vs.85).aspx
$sm = New-Object Microsoft.Search.Interop.CSearchManagerClass

# Retrieves a catalog by name and creates a new ISearchCatalogManager 
# object for that catalog.
$catalog = $sm.GetCatalog("SystemIndex")

# Resets the underlying catalog by rebuilding the databases 
# and performing a full indexing. 
#
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266414(v=vs.85).aspx
$catalog.Reset()
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, which implies that the `#Requires` keyword can not handle this situation.

Comment: No, not assemblies. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires. The #Requires statement prevents a script from running unless the Windows **PowerShell version**, **modules**, **snap-ins**, and module and snap-in version prerequisites are met. If the prerequisites are not met, Windows PowerShell does not run the script.